# Case insensitive string comparison in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, comparison

Can someone explain why this is the case?

```js
console.log('AB_CD' > 'AB_C_D'); //false
console.log('ab_cd' > 'ab_c_d'); //true
```

Comment: `"A".charCodeAt(0)` -> 65; `"a".charCodeAt(0)` -> 97; `"_".charCodeAt(0)` -> 95

Comment: Because `_` is [larger than any upper-case letter but smaller than any lower-case letter](http://www.asciitable.com/mobile/), i.e. `'D' < '_' ` (first line) but `'d' > '_'` (second line)

Comment: Check the ascii table

Comment: I see... haven't thought  '_' is in between... thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are compared using **character codes**, which you can learn more about reading [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/js-array-sort-strings)

In this first comparison (`'AB_CD' > 'AB_C_D'`), the character code for `D` and `_` are `68` and `95`, respectively, which explains why the expression evaluates as `false`.

```
A: 65; A: 65
B: 66; B: 66
_: 95; _: 95
C: 67; C: 67
D: 68; _: 95
```

In the second comparison (`'ab_cd' > 'ab_c_d'`), the character code for `d` and `_` are `100` and `95`, respectively, which explains why the expression evaluates as `true`.

```
a: 97;  a: 97
b: 98;  b: 98
_: 95;  _: 95
c: 99;  c: 99
d: 100; _: 95
```